# LearnR generates "Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another' when calling DT::datatable()

Tags: r, shiny, dt, learnr

The following learnR tutorial generates an error when it is "run", and the code box's run button is pressed. The notebook works fine if I omit the `DT:datable` function but I need to use this in my true implementation in order to get access to the **escape** parameter.

```
---
output: 
  learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(learnr)
``
``{r tst1, exercise = TRUE, exercise.eval = TRUE}
data(iris, package = "datasets")
DT::datatable(iris)
``
```

For formatting reasons I have only shown two backticks for the code blocks above instead of the normal three.

Comment: Hi Nick, I can't reproduce your issue from the example above. Can you please open a new issue in the learnr repo and include the output from `devtools::session_info()`? https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues

Answer (score 0):

After checking my versions of packages using `sessionInfo()` is decided to reinstall *learnr* and *rlang* as these were both github versions rather than CRAN versions. **Amazingly, this fixed the problem.** I cannot say which of the two was at fault.